# mod_evasive not getting updated on centos7

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-evasive

I am trying to integrate mod_evasive with httpd on centos7. Module is installed and getting loaded by httpd upon restart. However, it is not picking up the parameters specified in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf` file as specified below.

> LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive24.so
>   `<IfModule mod_evasive24.c>`
>   DOSHashTableSize    3097
>   DOSPageCount        20
>   DOSSiteCount        50
>   DOSPageInterval     1
>   DOSSiteInterval     1
>   DOSBlockingPeriod   10
>   DOSEmailNotify   xyz@mail.com
>   DOSLogDir           "/var/log/mod_evasive"
>   `</IfModule>`

I am testing the performance by one perl script as-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# test.pl: small script to test mod_dosevasive's effectiveness
use IO::Socket;
use strict;
for(0..300) {
my($response);
my($SOCKET) = new IO::Socket::INET( Proto   => "tcp",
                                  PeerAddr=> "172.31.19.247:80");
if (! defined $SOCKET) { die $!; }
print $SOCKET "GET /?$_ HTTP/1.0\n\n";
$response = <$SOCKET>;
print $response;
close($SOCKET);
}
```

Command executed by me is `perl test.pl > sample.txt`
In sample.txt, I'm getting `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` for first 120 requests and `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` for all the remaining requests.  But as per my understanding, the configuration set,  It should have to start denying beyond 50 requests as specified in `DOSSiteCount` in `mod_evasive.conf` file.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: remove the IfModule tag and try again in case there is some naming mismatch. The module identifier is different from the name of the module file and also the official page suggests and IfModule with a different module identifier. The whole ifmodule usage thing is unnecessary if you are going to use the module anyways.

Comment: Hi ezra-s, I tried by removing the "IFModule", still same result

Comment: I am mostly interested in the dependency between "DOSPageCount" and "DOSSiteCount". How they are inter-related?

Comment: Is the Github repo:  jzdziarski / mod_evasive the proper repo for mod_evasive? I worry that its last update was on Feb 22, 2017